# How to control an interactive shell (e.g. vim) from another machine?

Tags: linux, shell, vim, tmux, bluetooth

My problem is: my bluetooth keyboard won't work with my new android phone (big screen), but it does work with my old android phone (small screen).

So I'd like to connect the keyboard to my old phone and stream its keystrokes to my new phone; type there, look here.

I'd also like the actual session and files to be on the new phone - but I guess that's not essential. They could be on the old phone, and only the display is mirrored/cast to the new phone.

Seems to me:

1. how to pipe input into one shell from another
2. how to pipe input from one machine to another

I've tried: `tmux` screen mirroring over wifi, but latency is too high.

I'm mostly using vim, so something using that would work too.

Would bluetooth have lower latency than wifi? Can you have a keyboard and a hotspot over bluetooth at the same time? Not sure how to setup a  bluetooth connection, and I *guess* the latency is elsewhere, probably in `tmux`.

It seems that getting low latency should be easy with two devices sitting next to each other...

Any ideas?

BTW: I've given up on connecting the kb and new phone; and reluctant to factory reset. I could get a new kb, but I like this one.

Comment: Why not you ssh to your old phone from your new phone, given they are on same network or reachable to each other via public internet or vpn .

Comment: @mkmayank Thanks fo the response! Although that would make the kb work, and would use files etc on the new phone, it would use the display of the old phone - I want to use the (bigger) display of the new phone... Is there a way for ssh to display what's happening on the new phone's display?

Comment: @mkmayank Though I'd like to use the display on the new phone, I realized it could be convenient to use the new phone for results (graphics), and code on the old - sweet, dual-monitor phone! So I tried your suggestion, and surprisingly it still had latency, so it seems to be wifi (same with telnet).

Comment: @mkmayank And it opened up other options: I could code locally (on old phone), and push to git on new phone, with a hook to compile and run it. Similar alternatives: send the src files, use vim's feature of local editing of a remote file, send the executable. So thanks very much for that! But my wifi idea really doesn't work for me. (maybe the latency is reasonable, and I'm just too sensitive to it). Maybe there's a bluetooth way...

Comment: Welcome, if it helps, though I still doesn't get the context of phone here, what is phone , a mobile phone (which keeps ringing to distract me) or something else ?

Comment: @mkmayank sorry, they're both android smartphones, running `termux`, which gives a pretty-much complere linux environment. BTW I just got bluetooth hotspot/internet sharing (instead of wifi) going at the same time as the bluetooth keyboard, and there's just about no latency at all!

Comment: wow, this is indeed a great tool, I also need to use
thanks for introducing this to me

Answer (score 0):

We `ssh` then share a `tmux` session, so we can type on the old phone and
view on the new phone.

A bluetooth hotspot has much lower latency than a wifi hotspot. Lag is usually imperceptible.

The bluetooth keyboard will be connected to the old phone.

1. **bluetooth hotspot** Setup bluetooth hotspot on new machine (Android
   5.1: `Settings->More->tethering and portable hotspot->bluetooth
   tethering`); on the old mark that machine for "internet sharing"
   (Settings->Bluetooth->icon on right of new phone's name->`use for:
   internet connection sharing`) NOTE: you don't have actually be online;
   it works in airplane mode too
2. **ssh** On the new phone, start ssh daemon with `sshd -D -p
   8080`; on old phone, connect to it with `ssh ssh://192.168.44.1:8080`.
   But if the old phone is the hotspot, connect to the client with `ssh
   ssh://192.168.44.40:8080`. The addressing is:

   - `ssh://192.168`

     - `.44` bluetooth

       - `.40` hotspot
       - `.1` client

Note: `-D` keeps `sshd` in the foreground so you can exit it with `^C`.
Otherwise you must find its job id with `ps aux |grep sshd` and `kill`
it. There's probably a better way to do it.

3. **tmux attach** On new phone, in a new terminal, setup your `tmux`
   session (e.g. `tmux`). On old phone in the ssh session, attach to
   tmux with `tmux attach`. Now both phones are connected to
   the same `tmux` session, so typing in either will appear in both.
4. **bluetooth keyboard** On old phone, connect the bluetooth keyboard.
   Now we can type on the old phone's bluetooth keyboard, and view on the
   new phone.  Put away the old phone, and it's as if the keyboard is
   connected to the new phone.

Note: `tmux` ignores extra rows and/or cols to match the connected
terminal - that's why you may see shaded of extra rows/cols on
right/bottom. Different display sizes, font sizes, or orientations
(portrait/landscape) can cause this.  To avoid this: on
the old phone, decrease the font until it has more rows and cols than the
new phone (so any extras are on the old phone).  To do this in `termux`,
use `ctrl alt -`, or pinch-zoom (two fingers moving towards each other):
https://termux.com/hardware-keyboard.html

---

PROBLEMS: it feels like you're on the new phone, but it's really only for
that `tmux` session.  e.g. other keystrokes operate on the old phone:
`termux` font size; `termux` create/switch sessions; android HOME key;
android app-switch (`ctrl-TAB`).  A strange experience is the phone
entering sleep as you type, because its input devices aren't used.

There also seems to be issues with getting disconnected sometimes. I've
only just tried it, but I expect all of these problems are standard
`tmux`, `ssh` or bluetooth hotspot issues.